# Why adding 0 to a variable?

Tags: c, delphi

I am porting [C source code](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/C/geodesic_8c_source.html) to [Delphi](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi).

I find in that source a lot of occurrences of code similar to this (Here line 190):

```
if (x != 0) { *sinx += (real)(0); *cosx += (real)(0); }
```

We are in this context:

```
typedef double real;
real  x;
real* sinx;
real* cosx;
```

I wonder how adding 0 could be useful.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me. It's probably useless code that has no consequence. Make some tests with the original code vs. code where you've removed that part and check if th results are the same.

Comment: The comment says it relates to handling of -0

Comment: Look at the comment line 175. It was mentioned that VS had problems dealing with `-0`. I guess it is a way to insure values are not equal to `-0`. Certainly no longer needed

Comment: @Damien Line 175 is included in a conditional compilation and is another problem. If it was the same problem, line 190 would also be conditionally compiled IMO.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sure, but what does it? Adding 0 to -0 result in 0?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I really doubt that it is useless code. What I am translated is a very good library and is maintained for years. At one place it could be forgotten but not at so many places. There is for sure a very good reason to do that.

Comment: Yes, that's how I read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Comment: I wonder why you translate rather than compile this code. Compiling it means you don't risk making mistakes, and the code will execute much faster.

Comment: I translate because I need the code in a Delphi application and don't want to depend on a DLL. btw: thanks for the link about signed 0.

Comment: Does Object Pascal support other signedness formats than 2's complement? Because C unfortunately does. Someone might have decided it was a "great" idea to support 1's complement or signed magnitude formats, each having negative zero.

Comment: Actually, I've looked more closely. The handling for -0 is in a conditional statement above so I'm not sure that's it.

Comment: Depending on DLLs is way cleaner. And faster, if that matters to you. And you can keep up with any developments to the code. I don't understand this viewpoint.

Comment: @fpiette Btw you are aware of C++ Builder yeah? Basically Delphi wearing a C++ overcoat. C++ Builder can generate any form of lib you'd like to use in Delphi, including VCL components "bpl" packages etc etc.

Comment: @Lundin Of course I know C++ Builder. But I'm writing a software that I will open source, targeted at Delphi users. I want that my software can be used by Delphi developers having only Delphi at their disposal and not depending on anything else. Only Delphi source code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My point is explained in my previous comment to Lundin. I will keep up with development because I keep the source code I translated and can compare it at anytime with future version. Since this library is very mature (2012) it won't probably change much. And I only need a small part of it.

Comment: @fpiette: Would it be possible to ask the author of the code?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Sorry for my bad English: I don't understand if you suggest I contact the author of the code or if you want to contact him.

Comment: @fpiette _you_ should contact him and deal directly with him

Comment: @Jabberwocky That will not be necessary. I now fully understand how it works and how I have to port the C-code to Delphi. See the answer I just wrote. It makes sense to add 0.0 to a value: it makes sure that if the value is -0.0 it becomes 0.0, in all other cases, the value is not changed.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for all having commented my question. It pushed me on the right track:

Adding 0.0 to -0.0 gives the result 0.0. Adding 0.0 to anything else has no effect. To say it in other words, adding 0.0 to a value will not change the value unless the value was -0.0 in which case the result will be 0.0.

This [article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero) explain that in IEEE 754 binary floating-point numbers, zero is a signed quantity. You can have -0.0 and +0.0.

The C source code makes a lot of efforts to preserve precision in floating point operation and for that purpose must take care of negative zero.

I checked that MSVC and Delphi handle floating point values (double data type) exactly the same way and so I simply have to exactly translate the C-code to Delphi and it works the same in both languages.

Comment: So effectively `+0` is added. Which in turn should mean that adding `-0` to `+0` would make it `-0`.

Comment: You should know that the 64 bit compiler, at least in some versions, doesn't implement unary negation correctly. So `-x` is +0 when x is +0. IIRC this was fixed in a recent release.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks. It's OK for me since I always use the latest version available. Anyway, I have check the code I translated by compiling for x32 and x64 (Windows) and it works as expected.

Comment: Oh. I thought you said you were making an open source library. I'm very confused.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What is confusing you? I'm doing an open source application, not an open source library.

Comment: When you said that "I always use the latest version" available, that implied to me that you would be in control of how the code was compiled. Which seemed at odds with open source. I was just trying to alert you to an issue that some Delphi users might have with negation in the Windows 64 bit compiler. But perhaps you don't want to concern yourself with Delphi versions that you yourself won't use. Other users of the code are not your concern? Is that it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Open source doesn't mean that the source could be compiled with any compiler chain. I'm using - as always - the latest Delphi version. I'll provide the source telling I used Delphi 10.4.1. For another matter, I developed a `library` (ICS) since Delphi 1 and still well alive. ICS is compatible with very old Delphi versions (More than 10 years). I know how difficult it is to maintain full compatibility. I won't do that with the `application` I'm currently developing. I will just provide the source as is on GitHub.

Comment: FWIW, I dug out the issue I submitted: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20350